# Jquery validator triggering error when calling valid function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, master-pages

I'm using JQUERY validator [plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) on my ASP.NET web forms with a master page. Obviously the FORM element is at master page. In one of the child form I have few divs with different input blocks. So I tried to initialise the validator like this

```
    $('#teambasic').validate({
        rules: {
            teamName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        }
    });

    $('#extradetails').validate({
        rules: {
            domain: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        }
    });
```

Each of these divs are in different steps of the wizard and on clicking next button Im calling the valid function. But on calling the function it triggers an error

```
jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.valid (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at <anonymous>:1:32
```

On googling I found there could be a chance of this error if the inputs are outside the form tag. But in my case its all inside the FORM tag in master page. I verified its using jquery

```
$('input[name=teamName]').parents('form').length
```

which returned 1 since it has the parent form. I am not able to figure out where the trouble is

Comment: You must have `name` attribute on control  to use this plugin. Are you missing name attribute ?

Comment: See this sample fiddle how to use name attribute to set rule. http://jsfiddle.net/740epqhb/

Comment: @Shree Yea, I have name attribute in the control
<input name='teamName'.......

Comment: You're not showing enough code to demonstrate the problem.  WHERE are you attaching the `.valid()` method?  Where is the rendered HTML markup?  You cannot have nested `form` elements with this plugin. That is invalid HTML.  You also absolutely cannot attach the `.valid()` method to a `div`, if that's what you did, hence the error message about an element.